# Leading slashes in JSON from Google Finance API call

Tags: php, json, google-finance

I've been using the Google Finance API to successfully gather some stock info.  The problem is that after a call to `http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=[$tickerSymbol]`, the JSON that Google returns has `//` added before it and therefore the string cannot be encoded using PHP's `json_encode()`.  The [JSONLint JSON Validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/) confirms that the `//`s are not valid. The obvious workaround is to strip the slashes from the beginning of the JSON.  None-the-less, I am left wondering why Google is adding slashes to the JSON it is returning.  Is there a purpose behind the extra slashes? Is this a quirk with PHP's `json_encode()` when other languages would simply ignore the extra characters? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Here is an example of the result of a request for `http://www.google.com/finance/info?infotype=infoquoteall&q=AAPL` with the leading slashes.

```
// [ {
"id": "22144"
,"t" : "AAPL"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "340.65"
,"l_cur" : "340.65"
,"ltt":"4:00PM EST"
,"lt" : "Jan 18, 4:00PM EST"
,"c" : "-7.83"
,"cp" : "-2.25"
,"ccol" : "chr"
,"el": "345.20"
,"el_cur": "345.20"
,"elt" : "Jan 18, 5:45PM EST"
,"ec" : "+4.55"
,"ecp" : "1.34"
,"eccol" : "chg"
,"div" : ""
,"yld" : ""
,"eo" : ""
,"delay": ""
,"op" : "327.05"
,"hi" : "344.76"
,"lo" : "326.00"
,"vo" : "66.34M"
,"avvo" : "11.28M"
,"hi52" : "348.48"
,"lo52" : "190.25"
,"mc" : "313.75B"
,"pe" : "22.49"
,"fwpe" : ""
,"beta" : "1.38"
,"eps" : "15.15"
,"name" : "Apple Inc."
,"type" : "Company"
}
]
```

Comment: I ran into this too, ever figure out what's up with this? The only thing I've noticed is that it seems to prepend the slashes when it's giving you an actual company (as opposed to a bunch of search results if it couldn't find the particular company). Very strange.

Comment: +1. Experiencing the same thing, and can't for the life of me understand why they append invalid characters to the response. I'm guessing it has something to do with security, but can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those looking for a ready answer, here is a working example with PHP; The JSON is cleaned and transformed into an object. Values can easily be extracted.

The second is just to make it more awesome, it sends a push message you a PubNub channel when page is accessed (cron is your friend). PubNub message can easily be received via javascript hence live...

```
<?php

  //Obtain Quote Info
  $quote = file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=INDEXDB:DAX');

  //Remove CR's from ouput - make it one line
    $json = str_replace("\n", "", $quote);

  //Remove //, [ and ] to build qualified string  
    $data = substr($json, 4, strlen($json) -5);

  //decode JSON data
    $json_output = json_decode(utf8_decode($data));

  // get the last price
    $last = $json_output->l;

  //Output Stock price .
  echo 'DAX: ' . $last; 


//////////////////////////////
//  send it through pubnub  //
//////////////////////////////

require_once('Pubnub.php');

// Publish and Subscribe Keys 
$publish_key   = 'demo';
$subscribe_key = 'demo';
$subscribe_key = false;

// Create Pubnub Object
$pubnub = new Pubnub( $publish_key, $subscribe_key, $secret_key );

// Publish !
$channel = 'quoteTheDax';

$timestamp = $pubnub->time();
$pubish_success = $pubnub->publish(array(
    'channel' => $channel,
    'message' => array("last" => $last2, "ts" => $timestamp)
));

//Boom its send to ppl subscribed to this channel arround the world
?>
```

of course if you need something live updating all the time there are better options. I was just looking to update every 30min/60min.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because google don't want you to work with that JSON, they  recommend to use the Google Data API.

Comment: Any reason for that theory?  Seems they would just block the JSON if they didn't want one to work with it.

Comment: Of course:  I can't find any documentation about using the JSON. But I can see for example on the JS-API-docs the following *The underlying representation of the data is JSON, but the client library provides an abstraction layer so you don't have to work with the JSON data directly.*