# Json object in jquery can't be read?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to read the finance info from the google page into a json object.

Code is below:

```
            try {
                $.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:GOLDBEES&jsoncallback=?",function(data){
                    alert(data);//var jsondata = data;
                    //jsonobj = $.parseJSON(jsondata);
                    //alert(jsonobj[0].id);
                });
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e.toString());
            }
```

However I keep getting this error all the time on firebug

```
   invalid label
   "id": "4052464"
```

Is there any way this info can be read. My ultimate goal is to create a windows 7 gadget that doesnt use server side scripting and can be used from any Windows 7 system.

Appreciate all the help.

John

Answer (score 2):

Response isn't valid JSON (response is prefixed with //), so jQuery won't be able to parse it correctly anyway.

To solve change `&jsoncallback=?` to `&callback=?`

so

```
$.getJSON("http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:GOLDBEES&callback=?", function(data) {
    alert(data)
});
```

Comment: ...which tells Google to return a valid JSON-P response, to avoid cross-domain issues.

Comment: thnx for finishing my post @T.J.Crowder ;-) hehe

Comment: this is perfect!!! I just completed my code by adding this bit "alert(data[0].id)"

Answer (score 0):

The [response from Google](http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:GOLDBEES&jsoncallback=?) has two leading `/`'s, making the response invalid JSON... [for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730163/leading-slashes-in-json-from-google-finance-api-call).

Because of this, you cannot use `jQuery.getJSON`, as it expects a JSON response. Instead, you should use `jQuery.get`, and parse the JSON yourself after removing the two leading slashes.

```
jQuery.get('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NSE:GOLDBEES&jsoncallback=?', function (string) {
    var validJson = string.slice(2);
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(validJSON);

    // use obj
});
```

Two additional points:

1. No JSONP is being used, so you don't need the `jsoncallback=?` in your request URL
2. The Windows Sidebar [has been retired](http://gallery.live.com), so you cannot publish you finished gadget to the official gallery.

Comment: *"No JSONP is being used"* Then he won't be able to access this data via `getJSON` at all, unless his page is on that same `http://finance.google.com` origin (thanks to the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)). JSON-P is indeed available on that endpoint, you just have to give it the right parameter as Manuel points out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Windows Sidebar Gadgets are not restricted by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: `@Matt`: Ah, good deal. Still, though, apparently Google requires you to use JSON-P with this endpoint, as they stick in that `//` but if you give the correct parameter, you get back a valid JSON-P response.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: They don't **require** you to.. you just have to slice the `//`'s off first.

Comment: `@Matt`: Fair enough, if you don't have the SOP issue and have direct access to the text.

Comment: @Matt thank you for the response... Yes i do understand that the gallery has been retired. this gadget is going to be something thats very personal to me... since I am trying to keep a track of my stocks using spreadsheets and having them on the desktop is perfect!!! :)